# How to kill mousemove after click in this jquery function?

Tags: jquery, click, mousemove

This is a button that follows mouse movement. I would like to stop this button when mouse is clicked on it!

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() { 

$( "#enbfb-button-wrapper-5" ).parent().mousemove( function( e ) { 

jQuery( "#enbfb-button-wrapper-5" ).css( { 
top: e.pageY - 10, left: e.pageX + 30

} ); 
} );
```

I think I have to kill mousemove! How to do that please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() { 

    var $btn = $( "#enbfb-button-wrapper-5" );
    $btn.parent().on('mousemove.wrappermove',  function( e ) { 
        $btn.css( { 
            top: e.pageY - 10, left: e.pageX + 30
        }); 
    });

    $btn.on('click', function(){
        $btn.parent().off('mousemove.wrappermove')
    })
});
```

Comment: This code disabled mousemove... Button doesn't follow mouse movements.

Answer (score 0):

on click event [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) mousemove event 
like 
i am giving an idea for more details see [Bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() { 

$( "#enbfb-button-wrapper-5" ).parent().mousemove( function( e ) { 

jQuery( "#enbfb-button-wrapper-5" ).css( { 
top: e.pageY - 10, left: e.pageX + 30

} ); 

$( "#enbfb-button-wrapper-5" ).parent().click( function( e ) { 

$( "#enbfb-button-wrapper-5" ).parent().unbind("mousemove");

} ); 


} );
```

Comment: button is still following mousemove after click! :(

Comment: see bind and unbind in jquery you will get your result i have just given an idea

Comment: give you html and js  and brother i am helping you just like my answer and vote up it is enough no nedd to say pay.....

Comment: Oh my friend.. alright: this is the demo page: http://glibee.com/test-5.html ... to watch video user has to click in like button.. then like button stop to follow mouse movements... can you help on that?

Comment: wait i am watching your demo

Comment: hey why you use enbfb_hider(); two time

Answer (score 0):

you mean like:

```
$( "#enbfb-button-wrapper-5" ).parent().on('mousemove click', function(e) {
   if(e.type == 'mousemove') {
        $( "#enbfb-button-wrapper-5" ).css( { 
          top: e.pageY - 10, left: e.pageX + 30
        });
   }
   else if(e.type == 'click') {
        $( "#enbfb-button-wrapper-5" ).parent().unbind('mousemove');
   }
});
```

Comment: This code disabled mousemove... Button doesn't follow mouse movements.

Comment: Yes, did some adjusts here... Button is following mouse movements with your code... I've change .on for .bind ... But after click button is still following mouse movements...